# Should the Tomcat standalone http server be stopped after you've setup the apache http server?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, unix, tomcat

I'm going to set up my linux server (ubuntu) with Apache and Tomcat. I've seen the documentation about setting up the tomcat connector for apache, but the thing I don't understand is that shouldn't you stop the tomcat standalone http server that's listening on port 8080 once you've setup apache to handle the requests? None of the docs say anything about that. Or is something during the configuration preventing that part from running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our setup, we leave it open but not public.  We have a load balanced setup, and this allows us to still hit each tomcat server individually, outside of the connector, so we can see what each individual machine is returning.  This is sometimes useful in debugging.  We do not have this open to the outside world though, because we want to ensure that normal traffic goes through the connector.

Answer (score 2):

The 8080 connector is typically listening on the localhost interface only. So, even if you do not turn it off, it should be okay as it is not accessible from the rest of the network. However, I would recommend only enabling it for debugging purposes, like when you want to determine if the cause of a problem is on the Tomcat side or the Apache side of things.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying. But just to humor me, would I just un-comment the <Connector> element from server.xml to turn that off if I really wanted to?